# Htaccess - pass case sensitive subdomain to errorpage

Tags: .htaccess

Im not very familiar with .htacces and conditions and rules.

So far i have obviously failed to understand it. - Solution might be simple and straigth forward.

I have looked through posts and lots of google searches, and now im here posting my question.

I am doing a project where case sensitive ticker-code can be send to my site, as follows:

Examples:

This works: mydomain.com/LeUj

This works: mydomain.com#LeUj

This does not: LeUj.mydomain.com

The ticker-code is send to my errorpage, but it is forced to lower-case, which not works with my service.

Any help is really appreciated.

Thanks

My .htaccess file so far:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /4_nul_4.php?url=%{REQUEST_URI}


RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.mydomain\.com$
RewriteRule !^4_nul_4\.php?url=%{REQUEST_URI}$ 4_nul_4\.php?url=%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

Comment: Not sure what you want there is actually possible. Host names are supposed to be case-insensitive, see https://serverfault.com/q/672984 And I think common browsers normalize to lowercase before they even make the request (at least trying to request `https://ABC.example.com`, and then checking the request in dev tools in my current browser suggests that), so the upper-/mixed-case version likely never even reaches your server to begin with.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @CBroe

No, i think you are right. I have tried it too. 

I guess i have to remove that entry possibility

Comment: @CBroe You should put that as an answer.

Comment: To preserve the case of the `Host` header when making the HTTP request you would need to manually construct the request using CURL or similar (which does work). But, as stated, if you are making the request via a browser then the browser itself lowercases the `Host` header before making the request. (Apache does match the `Host` header case-insensitively - as it should do - when routing the request on the server. But any server-side application needs to be careful to make a case-insensitive comparison on the `Host` header because Apache does not normalize it.)

Comment: `!^4_nul_4\.php?url=%{REQUEST_URI}$` - Your `RewriteRule` _pattern_ will always be successful. You can't embed server variables in the regex like that.

Comment: "But any server-side application needs to be careful to make a case-insensitive comparison on the `Host` header" - This includes in the Apache config files, like `.htaccess`. Generally, you should be using the `NC` flag when comparing against the `Host` header (ie. `HTTP_HOST`).